# Sufficient ssd for Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, disk-space

This is my first query , and also my first apple product, macbook pro retina.

Should I be buying 128 or 256 as I am really tight on budget.

I have 2 tb of external but I dont know I could make use of it.
I do some programming on Java and c and also python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 128 is just on the border.

Comment: Should go for the 256

Comment: 128 could work depending how much media you want to store but you might find yourself deleting files to make up space for that occasional 2.5 GB download. I'm glad I decided to go for the 256, I have around 90 GB of free space. I use the machine for coding for the most part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

128Gb is plenty, with the condition it it is only plenty if you do not have much media (pictures, music, video). I have set up plenty of company laptops with 128Gb SSD drives, none are in any danger of running out of space.

If you have media, and can offload it to an external drive , then you are still fine. iTunes and Photos both allow the media library to go anywhere you want.

Comment: Concur.  Even if you save 1TB of your external for Time Machine (highly recommended) you still have an extra TB for storage of media.